# Infinite loop search page

Tags: redirect, catalogsearch

While accessing the search url (http://localhost/mage2/catalogsearch/result/ or http://localhost/mage2/catalogsearch/result/index) infinite loop. Is it possible  redirect to home page?
Thanks.

Comment: you dont want search functionality?? when someone access http://localhost/mage2/catalogsearch/result/index this url than it will redirect to homepage right?

Comment: I need a search functionality. Some users access those urls need redirect to home page or 404 page.

Comment: if you want to redirect that url than you need to put the redirect code to htaccess file

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/redirect-301-htaccess-in-magento/